# Perl: Create a hash whose keys and values come from a given array?

Tags: perl

I want to convert an `array` to `hash` in given format:

```
@array = ('a', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'b', 6, 7, 8);

%hash = ('a' => [1,2,3,4], 'b' => [6,7,8]);
```

Comment: How do you know which array elements are keys and which are values?

Comment: `map { /[a-z]/ ? $x=$_:  push @{$hash{$x}},$_ } @array;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
my @array = ('a',1,2,3,4,'b',6,7,8);
my %hash;
my $r;

tr/0-9//c ? $r= ($hash{$_}=[]) : push(@$r, $_) for @array;

print Dumper \%hash;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
      'b' => [
               6,
               7,
               8
             ],
      'a' => [
               1,
               2,
               3,
               4
             ]
    };
```

Comment: `$hash{$_} ||= []` if hash keys are to be repeated.